# My TextBox vanishes when I add a VisualState

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to use Visual States in a Windows Phone 8 application (C#-XAML). The screen is dark. Here is the style I defined in App.xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="StyleDeBaseTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="InputScope" Value="Text"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40px"/>
    </Style>
```

It works, but when the TextBox has the focus, its background becomes white. As the foreground color remains white, you can't read what you write. So, I added this property, but the result is that my TextBox disappears (though I get no error message):

```
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" To="Green" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone Control Template : [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj710191.aspx)

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             To="0"
                                                                             Duration="0" />
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             To="0"
                                                                             Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                                    Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                           Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                           FontStyle="Normal"
                                                           Text="&#xE0A4;"
                                                           FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBackgroundThemeOpacity}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                      Grid.Row="0"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}"
                                      Margin="0,4,0,4"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      FontWeight="Semilight" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                  ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  IsTabStop="False"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" 
                                  IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

TextBox vanishes because you override its `ControlTemplate` and doesn't provide any content host.

Copy the default template of TextBox from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and change the StoryBoard as per your needs.

---

Anyhow this is `ControlTemplate` which you can use. It also change border brush to green on focus. Hope this is what you want:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxBase">
   <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
           Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
           Name="border"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      Name="PART_ContentHost"
                      Focusable="False" />
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="UIElement.Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border"
                Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border"
                Value="Green"/>
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: In this template, with what should I replace the DynamicResource (they cause an error while compiling) ? I tried to put simple values instead, but nothing appears. When I put a red background to the border, I can see only the border of the control : its height is about 4px.

Comment: For all DynamicResources used in there, you need to copy those resources as well defined below the style.

Comment: I have added controlTemplate which you can use. See if that helps.

Comment: Well, actually, I still have a compilation problem : the tag 'Trigger' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. And TextBoxBase is unknown too.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `WPF`? Triggers exist in WPF, not in Windows Phone 8. Moreover, posted MSDN link also works. All you have to do style and all dynamic resources used over there.

Comment: Indeed, it is a windows phone application. That's why it didn't work. Sorry for the flag WPF, I thought it included windows phone.

Comment: But you tagged your question with WPF. Anyways copying DynamicResources along with Style works?